# Restricted bluetooth functionality when device is paired

Tags: 2.1-eclair

I have a bluetooth enabled car stereo, with my iphone I'm able to connect to it, and then use the device to browse through the music on my ipod/make calls etc. The bluetooth pairing basically enables me to operate the phone via my car dashboard.

I've tried doing this on my Orange San-Francisco / XTE (android 2.1) but I can't get the same outcome.

The device is correctly paired (or so the phone says). If a call comes in/or I make a call from the handset, it gets detected and then sounded over the handsfree system.

BUT,

Using my stereo I'm unable to browse through my phones contact book, or to play any audio from my phone.

I'm thinking, is there an option in the bluetooth settings that determine what paired devices have access to? i.e, tapping into the phones contact book / music could be disabled?

Comment: Which car stereo do you have?  I'm not that familiar with this type of syncing but it could be 2 things: the stereo not fully supporting Android or Android not supporting the necessary BT profile.  Seeing the model of stereo may help the community diagnose the problem.

Comment: Sorry probably should have added that, its a JVC KD-R711. http://www.halfords.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/product_storeId_10001_catalogId_10151_productId_770531_langId_-1_categoryId_165474

Answer (score 1):

Just reading the description on the stereo page you linked to, it sounds like it has built-in software to extend the normal bt profiles to allow 2-way control of ipods and iphones. This extended functionality won't translate to your android device unless JVC comes out with a firmware update for your stereo that supports android.

Answer (score 0):

Pairing is not enough, is it connected?

In the Bluetooth settings you can do a long touch on the device to get into device-specific options.